# Potential energy required to setup a charged shell of charge Q

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential-energy

[image]

As shown in my textbook we find work done to bring **dq** charge from infinity and integrate it to get total work.But if we cannot bring  whole Q charge at once then place on that metallic shell then whole Q on metallic shell will spread by itself on metal because metallic shell would try to become equipotential.in this case work done is zero but why this contradiction appears.

Answer (score 0):

Note that work done will not be zero because if we bring big amount of charge instead of **dq ** we have to consider the charges induced on metallic  shell.And if it were nonmetallic shell then we have to do work in spreading that charge over surface unlike metallic shell charge would not spread automatically but there will be no induced charges.so for conclusion in each case work done will be same.